# Lync 2013 (in VDI) Audio Issue

Tags: lync, vdi, lync-2013, citrix-receiver

We have a Citrix VDI environment where users log in using Citrix Receiver on their VDI. In their VDI (Windows 7,) Lync 2013 does not play notification sounds for incoming messages. I have checked the settings and they all appear to be set correctly for playing these sounds, and other pieces of software play sounds including all default Windows System sounds.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: When a message comes in and the sound would be played, does the Volume control show any activity on its sound meter?  In this VDI setup do they each get a VM spun up for them?

Comment: Great test... but no :(